# understanding output from opencv neural network

Tags: opencv, neural-network

I am testing the opencv neural network.
The training input I am using is

```
12 16 14
10 5  7.5
8  10 9
5  4  4.5
12 6  9
```

Finding the mean of the two numbers and the third one is the expected output. I am using 3 levels with 2 neurons for the input, 3 for hidden and 1 for output with equal weights.
I am using back propagation technique.

The output I am getting for

```
Predict(0,0);  ----> 13.121479
Predict(40,60);  ----> 6.043900
Predict(120,180);  ----> 5.801756
Predict(10,5);  ----> 10.095689
```

can someone explain the prediction results I am getting.

Comment: can you give us the weights of all neuron-connections?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565115/approximating-function-with-neural-network

Comment: weights are all same and i set them to 1