# How does a function approximation (say sine) in Neural network really works?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, approximation

I am learning neural networks for the first time. I was trying to understand how using a single hidden layer function approximation can be performed. I saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565115/approximating-function-with-neural-network) on stackexchange but I had some questions after going through [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575515/567812).

Suppose I want to approximate a sine function between 0 and 3.14 radians. So will I have 1 input neuron? If so, then next if I assume K neurons in the hidden layer and each of which uses a sigmoid transfer function. Then in the output neuron(if say it just uses a linear sum of results from hidden layer) how can be output be something other than sigmoid shape? Shouldn't the linear sum be sigmoid as well? Or in short how can a sine function be approximated using this architecture in a Neural network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible and it is formally stated as the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem). It holds for any non-constant, bounded, and monotonically-increasing continuous activation function

I actually don't know the formal proof but to get an intuitive idea that it is possible I recommend the following chapter: [A visual proof that neural nets can compute any function](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html)

It shows that with the enough hidden neurons and the right parameters you can create step functions as the summed output of the hidden layer. With step functions it is easy to argue how you can approximate any function at least coarsely. Now to get the final output correct the sum of the hidden layer has to be [image: activation function inversed] since the final neuron then outputs: [image: final output formula]. And as already said, we are be able to approximate this at least to some accuracy.

Comment: Thank you. The second link was very helpful. I realized that I wasn't considering that I had to add bias separately inside each neuron of hidden layer.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Another way to implement bias is to create a dummy input neuron which always outputs 1 and the weight a hidden-layer-neuron has to that dummy neuron is the bias for that neuron.